# Soft Index (sifs) Compactor just stops working over time

Tags: infinispan

I am pretty new to infinispan as a product. I am running a few test scenarios to get a feel for things. My cache is local only using sifs. Everything starts out fine, I can see the data files being created, compacted and then removed as described. Over time however, I noticed the compactor just stops doing anything and as a result new files just continue to be created and the file system fills, there is no further intervention by the compactor at all.
The logs don't elude to any failure of any sorts (even in TRACE) but I notice that there is a consistent pattern. All files that are present, aside from the file in current use, are sized consistently at 16.7MB EXCEPT FOR a single file with a timestamp of around the time the compactor logs stop is noticeably smaller than the rest.

The results of the test execution are always the same, only the amount of time taken for the compactor to stop working changes.

Is this a common thing and simply related to expiry as is suggested in the doco?
Assuming that to be the case, what is the recommended implementation for "highly performant" production ready systems where local cache only is the requirement? I was looking at perhaps something like RockDB for example. Seems to me like sifs is perhaps for testing only, is that a reasonable assumption?

```
version: 14.0.8.Final

cache config is

cache-mode: LOCAL
shared: false
persistent-cache.timeout: 5m
cache.max-count: 1000
persistence.enabled: true
data-location: /tmp/data
index-location: /tmp/index
```

any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Please add your Infinispan version and cache configuration.

Comment: He's using 14.0.8.Final. Two SIFS bugs were fixed in more recent versions, so he should upgrade to the latest release

Comment: As of today I am using 14.0.11.Final. It is better yes. I am still able to reproduce the problem though. It looks like the compressor component is silently failing and that appears to kill it completely. The only way to then get it going again is to restart the test/component... I am able to get a more stable outcome by reducing the maxFileSize, I reduce down to about 4 MB and that seems to be the most stable. Not sure I understand why but it does work... My main question though is whether SIFS is production ready. It feels like the answer is perhaps no but I would like to hear your thoughts?